# Custom function works only on some parent functions of another package

Tags: r, lidr

In my personal package I have a couple of functions that are used within the `lidR` package.
I can't understand why the same function works if used with `catalog_apply` but gets an error if used with `pixel_metrics`. So, in the latter case, I have to load the single function in the Global environment to make it work.

Here an example code (`ctg`: catalog, `shp`: shapefile):

```
# code applied to the extracted field plots
> ads = clip_roi(ctg, shp, radius=shp$plot_rad) # extract plots
> opt_chunk_buffer(ads) <- 0
> opt_chunk_size(ads) <- 0
> opt_output_files(ads) <- ""

> metrics = catalog_apply(ads, cloud_metrics, func = .my_metrics)


# code applied to the whole area extent
> r = pixel_metrics(ctg, .my_metrics, res = gridRes)

error: cannot find function "my_metrics"
```

Taking inspiration from the author's work, `my_metrics` has been shortened to `.my_metrics` for a matter of ease, as follows:

```
#' @rdname my_metrics
#' @export
.my_metrics = ~my_metrics(X, Y, Z, ReturnNumber, Classification, ScanAngleRank, ht_slice=1, ht_max=NULL, min_pts=0, sar_thr=NULL)
```

Reading a bit around I thought that it could be probably related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38735617/same-r-function-works-as-function-object-in-global-env-does-not-work-when-loade)...but in my case the main packages used from the function (i.e. `lidR`, `terra`, `sf`) area already in the `Depends` section of the `DESCRIPTION`.

Might it be something related to how the `lidR` functions (i.e. `cloud_metrics` VS `pixel_metrics`) "interpret" mine?

Comment: I can't tell from what you've written what functions are in your package and what are in a separate package. `catalog_apply` is in which package, yours or another? Same with `pixel_metrics`. It would help if you could more clearly delineate what is happening in your personal package and which specific pieces in your package are calling functions from another package.

Comment: Please report a reproducible example on the github repo https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `pixel_metrics()` call leads down a path where `template_metrics()` gets called and [discards the environment associated with your `.my_metrics` formula](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/blob/c46e841abcfcd6bd7ab598ba5584db9dcdbae70f/R/metrics_template.R#L245-L247). All that is left is the expression, so your `my_metrics()` function must be visible in the environment where that expression is eventually evaluated.

It's more difficult to work out why `catalog_apply()` does *not* behave like this. I'd recommend asking the package author for further clarification.